# Updating object with vue set doesnt change in html inside socketio listener

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an chat app with vue for front where I listen for broadcasting from laravel.

I have data object for messages which I update with new messages when the chat is active.

Here is an update with used code:

```
data() {
   return {
    msg: '',
    chatlist: JSON.parse(this.chatusers),
     activeChats: [],
    chatData: {},
    openedChats: [],
    maxOpened: Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 320),
   }
},

methods: {
listener() {
    Echo.private('user.' + window.uid)
                .listen('Chat', (e) => {
        //first if is for active and opened chats and here reactivity doesnt work
        if (this.activeChats.includes(e.data.user.id) && this.openedChats.includes(e.data.user.id)) {
        this.$set(this.chatData[e.data.user.id].messages, e.data.message.id - 1 , e.data.message);
        setTimeout(function() {
                let chat = document.getElementById('chat-'+e.data.user.id);
                chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;
            }, 100);
        //second if is for inactive chats and here reactivity works
        }else if (!this.activeChats.includes(e.data.user.id)) {
            axios.post('/messages', {
                id: e.data.user.id
            }).then((res) => {
                this.chatData[e.data.user.id] = res.data;
                this.activeChats.push(e.data.user.id);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    let chat = document.getElementById('chat-'+e.data.user.id);
                    chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;
                }, 100);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        //third if is for active chats that are not opened on page, so its same as first and it does not work
        }else if(this.activeChats.includes(e.data.user.id) && !this.openedChats.includes(e.data.user.id) && this.openedChats.length < this.maxOpened) {
            this.openedChats.push(e.data.user.id);
            this.$set(this.chatData[e.data.user.id].messages, e.data.message.id - 1, e.data.message);
        }

    });
}
}
```

I am calling listener in `mounted`.

The objects are changing but there is no reactivity on side that is receiving the message, so problem may be in echo listen, but since for second if statement is working I am not sure what can be a problem...

Seems like setting object property from echo listen does not trigger the change..

Update:

I tried this:

I opened chat on click which populated chatData[e.data.user.id] same as I use when I get new message and chat is not opened..
Then:

```
listener() {
    Echo.private('user.' + window.uid)
                .listen('Chat', (e) => {
this.$set(this.chatData[e.data.user.id].messages, e.data.message.id - 1 , e.data.message);
});
}
```

I call this and it still did not work which means that if it does work out of laravel echo but not in, there must be a problem.

So I tried to look for problem and saw that objects are updating but not triggering the change.

I found stupid solution to add new variable as empty array that updates at same time and place where I update the object, like so:

```
this.$set(this.chatData[e.data.user.id].messages, e.data.message.id - 1 , e.data.message);
this.array.push(1);
```

And then I used this array in v-for next to v-for that is using object.

That part is important so it triggers the change of object too, why I dont know but it works :D

Comment: Could you add `chatData` and an example response?

Comment: not right at this moment but chat data is object of keys as user ids and values as objects for messages and user data as name image etc. messages is updated with example I added but html only updates if i call method. If it is done inside listening it works only when I change chatdata object but not messages object in chatdata

Comment: Could it be that `this` inside `.listen` is not the vue instance?

Comment: i will add whole code where i have 3 if statements and all 3 use this and 1 doesnt work and that one is when the chat is active and opened on screen and where i update messages object. Which is deep inside main object so why it does not work may be that... Messages object is updated but reactivity does not update in html

Comment: You are saying it yourself; There is an issue with the reactivity. You/we then have to dive in what might cause this issue. First of, as I asked in my previous comment: Are we sure that `this` is the correct instance? Does it actually have a `.$set` functon?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is actually created by the second part of the code:

> ```
>     //second if is for inactive chats and here reactivity works
>     }else if (!this.activeChats.includes(e.data.user.id)) {
>         axios.post('/messages', {
>             id: e.data.user.id
>         }).then((res) => {
>             this.chatData[e.data.user.id] = res.data;
>             this.activeChats.push(e.data.user.id);
>             setTimeout(function() {
>                 let chat = document.getElementById('chat-'+e.data.user.id);
>                 chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;
>             }, 100);
>         }).catch((err) => {
>             console.log(err);
>         });
> ```

Mainly the line:

> ```
> this.chatData[e.data.user.id] = res.data;
> ```

This is adding a new property to the `this.chatData` without passing it through a Vue.set, meaning that while you read it fine, any changes to this object are not tracked.

*What's inside data that is supposed to be tracked?* `data.messages`

Since this property is not tracked, any interaction with this won't result in the proper "reactivity", and requires

The fix for your problem is simple, make sure that new entries to the `chatData` structure are passed through the Vue set function:

```
this.$set(this.chatData, e.data.user.id, res.data);
```

Comment: that works, I found the problem :D triggering the change does not work for some reason in laravel echo listen, but when I add additional array, and change array with any data and use vfor for that array next to vfor for object, it triggers the change and everything works.... Why I dont know

Comment: why I know the second if is not the problem is because I remove  all  ifs and tried to work only with first one from if without if... Had no changes

Comment: If you run it only with the first block, there should be error sinside the console stating that `this.chatData[e.data.user.id]` is undefined

Comment: you dont understand I will update the question with the code I tried and why you answer is not right in this case.. wait a min